# Passing data from parent to child reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

How to pass data from parent to child. why this is not working?
cannot display data in child component

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        const customers = [ 'Guacamole', 'Beef', 'Bean' ];
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                1) DataGrid
                <Api customers = {this.customers} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
class Api extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.customers}
            </div>
        )}
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to go through [react tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) again. You question is really basic. And you need no help here.

Comment: Most likely you will have a lot of down votes if you will ask such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why this is not working?* Because `this.customers === null`

*How to pass data from parent to child?*

Either use `constant` properly

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        const customers = [ 'Guacamole', 'Beef', 'Bean' ];
        return (
            <div>
                1) DataGrid
                <Api customers = {customers} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
class Api extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.customers}
            </div>
        )}
}
```

Or use `state` properly:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            customers: [ 'Guacamole', 'Beef', 'Bean' ],
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                1) DataGrid
                <Api customers = {this.state.customers} />
                <div onClick={() => {this.setState({customers: ['Beef', 'Apple']})}}>Change state</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
class Api extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.customers}
            </div>
        )}
}
```

Or use `this` properly:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.customers = [ 'Guacamole', 'Beef', 'Bean' ];
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                1) DataGrid
                <Api customers = {this.customers} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
class Api extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.customers}
            </div>
        )}
}
```

Comment: const customers = [{
  'ID': 1,'CompanyName': 'Super Mart of the West','Address': '702 SW 8th Street'}, {
 'ID': 2,'CompanyName': 'Electronics Depot','Address': '2455 Paces Ferry Road NW','City': 'Atlanta','State': 'Georgia','Zipcode': 30339,'Phone': '(800) 595-3232','Fax': '(800) 595-3231',
  'Website': 'http://www.nowebsitedepot.com'
}],
 error 'Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ID, CompanyName, Address, City, State, Zipcode, Phone, Fax, Website}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.'

Comment: If you want to change state (customers in your case) you should use  `this.setState`, like this: `this.setState(['Guacamole', 'Beef'])`

Comment: I have updated my answer, part `Or use state properly:` so you have idea how that should work.

Comment: const customers = [{
  'ID': 1,
'CompanyName': 'Super Mart of the West',
'Address': '702 SW 8th Street'}, {
 'ID': 2,
'CompanyName': 'Electronics Depot',
'Address': '2455 Paces Ferry Road NW'
}],
 error 'Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ID, CompanyName, Address}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.'

Comment: error message is straightforward: `error 'Objects are not valid as a React child'`
when you pass child like this` <div>{this.props.customers}</div>`
react expects `String` `Node` `Array of strings or nodes`
but you pass `Array of Objects`

Comment: Correct way is:
`<div>this.props.customers.map(item => <div key={item.ID}>{item.CompanyName}</div>)</div>`

Comment: Thanks. I am using Devextreme datagrid. 
<DataGrid
     dataSource={datasource} // this is where I need to pass data to the grid.
      >
How can I use props here? 
Columns are created in following manner:
<Column dataField={'Product'} groupIndex={0} />
        <Column
          dataField={'Amount'}
          caption={'Sale Amount'}
        />
how can I implement "this.props.customers.map(item => <div key={item.ID}>{item.CompanyName}" here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use React `state`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      customers =['Guacamole', 'Beef', 'Bean'];
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        1) DataGrid
        <Api customers={this.state.customers} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;

class Api extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.customers}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Or you can use just variable without `state`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  customers = ['Guacamole', 'Beef', 'Bean'];
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        1) DataGrid
        <Api customers={this.customers} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
class Api extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.customers}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

`const customers = [ 'Guacamole', 'Beef', 'Bean' ];`

to

`this.customers = [ 'Guacamole', 'Beef', 'Bean' ];`

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `customers` variable as a `const` inside the `constructor`.
This variable will live while this method is executing, then it is gone.

You have to do something like `this.customers`, this way, the variable will be a property of the instance of your component, available in other methods. You can use both `this.state` as suggests by @kkangil, or just `this.customers`. The difference is that React keeps track of `state` in other to tigger re-rendering.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.customers = [ 'Guacamole', 'Beef', 'Bean' ];
  }
  // ...
}
```